# Prisma Client returning an empty array on query

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express, prisma

I am setting up my backend project and have switched from Sequelize to Prisma for more robust querying. Going through Prisma's docs was hard, however I feel like I have all the bases covered.
Basically, I created the generator client and datasource db, I ran `prisma db pull` to generate the model, then ran `prisma generate` to update the prisma client. My client has basic logging enabled, verifying that it isconnected to the database.

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
    log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error'],
})
```

```
prisma:info Starting a mssql pool with 9 connections.
prisma:info Performing a TLS handshake
prisma:warn Trusting the server certificate without validation.
prisma:info TLS handshake successful
prisma:warn Turning TLS off after a login. All traffic from here on is not encrypted.
prisma:info Database change from 'RiffTheoryScales' to 'master'
prisma:info Changed database context to 'RiffTheoryScales'.
prisma:info SQL collation changed to windows-1252
prisma:info Microsoft SQL Server version 1443102736
prisma:info Packet size change from '4096' to '4096'
prisma:query SELECT [dbo].[Scales].[ID], [dbo].[Scales].[name]
WHERE [dbo].[Scales].[ID] = @P1
[]
```

My server looks like this

```
const prisma = new PrismaClient({
    log: ['query', 'info', 'warn', 'error'],
})

const app = express()
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())

// ROUTES
app.use('/api/scales', router);

const server = app.listen(3000, () =>
    console.log(`RUNNING ON PORT 3000`),
)

export default prisma
```

My schema looks like this

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Scales {
  ID                   Int     @id(map: "PK__Scales__3214EC27E22038C6") @default(autoincrement())
  name                 String  @db.NVarChar(100)

}
```

My basic test route looks like this

```
import { Router } from "express" ;
import getScaleByName from '../controllers/prismacontrol.js'

const router = Router(); 

router.get("/name", getScaleByName);

export default router
```

```
import prisma from "../servertwo.js";

const getScaleByName = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const scales = await prisma.scales.findMany()
        console.log(scales)

        if (!scales) {
            res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'No scales found!',
            });
        } else {
            res.status(200).json({
                scales,
                success: true,
                message: 'All scales returned'
            })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            message: `ERROR: ${error.message}`
        });
    }
}


export default getScaleByName
```

I thought I had all my bases covered but if anyone sees something missing or coding suggestions, point it out. It might even be something simple...

Comment: The problem is that it is returning an empty array with status 200 instead of returning status 400? If it is I'll answer your question

Comment: a query needs a FROM clause and you don't provide one

Comment: @Kobra yes and no. I just want it to return something at this point....I'll worry about error handling later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused with what you wanted, so I'll answer to two questions.

1. If your problem is that the empty arrays are going to the route with `status 200`, you just need to change the `if(!scales)` to `if(scales.length === 0)`, because in Javascript, an empty array is considered an existing array, so it will return `true`, just like an empty object.
2. If the problem is that it is returning an empty array instead of returning all the rows of a table, the only problem I could see is that your DB is not populated, or if the `connection string` is wrong.

For the last case, try using `npx prisma studio` to check if all data is being rendered by Prisma

Also check if the `env` is being read in the `schema`

Comment: Having npx prisma studio helped a lot actually! The issue actually lied within the master database and the actual database holding the same table somehow so it was getting confused. Thanks a lot tho

Comment: Happy to help friend!